# How to plot a fitted curve over a categorical boxplot in PyPlot? Why does the result differ from the same plot in Google Sheets?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, google-sheets

I have the following csv data:

```
Dataset Size,MAPE,MAE,STD MAPE,STD MAE
35000,0.0715392337,23.38300578,0.9078698348,2.80407539
26250,0.06893431034,22.34732326,0.9833948236,1.926517044
17500,0.0756695622,26.0900766,0.6055443674,8.842862631
8750,0.07176532526,23.02646184,0.8284005282,2.190506033
4200,0.08661127364,29.89234607,0.9395831421,7.587818412
2100,0.08072315267,27.20110884,0.03956974712,4.948606892
1050,0.07505202908,27.04025924,0.841966778,4.550482956
700,0.07703248113,26.17923045,0.4468447145,1.523638508
350,0.08695408769,32.35331585,0.7891190087,4.18648457
200,0.09770903032,30.96197823,0.04648972591,3.892800694
170,0.1202382169,41.87828814,0.7257680584,6.70453713
150,0.1960949784,77.20321559,0.5661066006,21.57418682
```

From the above data, I would like to generate the following plot using matplotlib or similar (seaborn, pandas, etc.):

[image: Example Plot Generated In Google Sheets]

```
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import animation
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

nr_datapoints = 10
def exponenial_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c
def myplot(data_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(data_file)
    print(df.head())

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # Exponential line fit
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponenial_func, np.array([float(i) for i in range(len(df['Dataset Size']))]), df['MAPE'], p0=(0, 0.0145, 0.0823))
    xp = np.linspace(0,len(df['Dataset Size']), 100)  
    plt.plot(xp, exponenial_func(xp, *popt), color = 'g')
    # barplote with error bars
    ax.bar([str(s) for s in df['Dataset Size']], df['MAPE'], yerr=df['STD MAPE'])
    plt.title('Accuracy of Model vs. Dataset Size')
    plt.xlabel('Dataset Size')
    plt.ylabel('Mean Absolute Percentage Error')
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

The plot that I get looks as follows:
    [image: Graph produced by the above code]

Why do I end up with a line rather than a curve from my code despite fitting an exponential function to the data? (Given that the google sheets plot does the same thing, e.g. fitting an exponential curve to the data)

Comment: Can you share the data file provided as argument in function `myplot`?

Comment: The errors bars on your plot are much larger than on the google plot, thats why the exponential fit looks almost linear.

Comment: From what I see, `curve_fit` function returns `b ~ 2.50970872e-05` which is very small. And note that for small values `epx(x)` is approximately `1 + x`. Hence you see the near linear line.

Comment: @Alex: That is because Google Slides cannot do error bars properly and would require a hacky workaround to allow for appropriate standard deviation error bars on each bar. (I just included them in the plot as an example, but they are actually just 10% of each bar height)

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you so much for your response. You are right, that is a problem. Is it possible that google sheets is doing a better job at fitting the curve than scipy? From eyeballing the plot, one would guess that a more curved line would fit the data better.

Comment: @DanielLima Please see the included CSV snipped above

Comment: @Alex: I think that is probably part of it. The curve is not very "curvy" and the error bars likely obscure the curvature due to the plot height being partially distorted by the large error bar on the "150" Data Set Size Bar.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Should I leave this question or delete it? I seem to have already had a good solution, but just failed to interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around with some functions, and I think I can say with some degree of certainty that the Google Sheets exponential function has a form close to this:

```
def sheetey_exponential_function(x, a, b, c):
    return a * b ** (x + c)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the horizontal axis is not linear. Actually it is inversed linear. So if you want your fit to look like an exponential function, you need to replace `x` with `1/x`:

```
def exponenial_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b/x)+c
```

The result is the following:
[image]